# $\Pi_{i=1}^{p-1}(i-1)kp + i \equiv -1 \pmod p, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is a prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am studying Wilson's Theorem where the previous corollary came up to my mind. Is it a true one? If so, this might be a **generalized version of the Theorem.**

Comment: I think $p\equiv0\pmod p$?

Comment: Start with $i=1$ on the lhs.

Comment: consider the edited one. I forgot to put i after the kp.

Comment: @user236182 how??

Comment: so taking the last term, it will be congruent to -1 mod p. Is that right??

Comment: @user236182 consider the new edited version.

Comment: By the way, this is not a generalisation of Wilson's Theorem. It's actually a consequence of it. Wilson's Theorem (or really, the theorem plus basic modular arithmetic) tells you that the coefficient of $p$ in the $i^{th}$ term of the product on the left can be any integer, not just a multiple of $\left(i-1\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reduce all parts of the product on the left $\textrm{mod}\,p$ (now that you have edited the question), this says $\left(p-1\right)! \equiv -1 \left(\textrm{mod}\, p\right)$, so I'd say so.